Powershell: How to recursively copy one folder to another directories sub folders
I can't wrap my head around a forEach command.
I want to copy X:\PowerShell Scripts to every Folder (Designated with *) to X:\Companies\*\Software\PowerShell Scripts
What is the suggested way to do this via Powershell?
The idea is I'm updating code in one location and running this script to update against everyone, and don't have to manually update this script everytime a new company is added.
This is as far as I've gotten and I don't think it's the best commands
$dir = Get-ChildItem x:companies | ? {$_.PSIsContainer}

$dir | ForEach-Object {
  Set-Location $_.FullName;
  xcopy 'X:\PowerShell Scripts' 
}


You can use the built-in Copy-Item command, just specify -Recurse to get the nested items:
Get-ChildItem X:\companies -Directory |ForEach-Object {
  # construct path to Software sub-folder
  $softwarePath = Join-Path $_.FullName Software

  # test that the target path actually exists
  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $softwarePath) {
    # then use Copy-Item -Recurse
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath "X:\PowerShell Scripts" -Destination $softwarePath -Recurse
  }
  else {
    Write-Warning "Directory '$softwarePath' does not exist, skipping"
  }
}

